# How do I move the Docker folder to another disk?

Tags: docker, docker-desktop

I have been searching far and wide for a solution to this, but it doesnt present it self to me.
So far there have been plenty of answers to this question but none of them seem to work.
So I will be very specific as to what I need, I need to move this folder here;
"C:\Program Files\Docker" to litterally any other drive "D:\Docker" is fine to me, this folder "C:\Program Files\Docker" takes up 2,27 GB, and I don't want that on my C: drive.

Comment: Have you looked at something similar to https://exploringtm1.com/how-to-point-docker-at-a-different-drive/ already?

Comment: I already looked at that one, its not for the issue im having, thats for the containers, I need the entire thing including docker desktop to get off my C drive and onto any other.
Why Docker didnt ask me where it should go is pretty infuriating, im not sure why its not but I hope there is a fantastic explination.

Answer (score 2):

I know this question is quite old at this point, but you can cut and paste the Docker related folders that reside in `C:\Program Files\Docker` to wherever you wish Docker's app installation files to reside.

In my case I put them at `F:\Docker\app` and then created a symlink using CMD (as admin) and entering the following command:

`mklink /j "C:\Program Files\Docker" F:\Docker\app`

and received the following confirmation after success:

`Junction created for C:\Program Files\Docker <<===>> F:\Docker\app`

Answer (score 0):

Have a look at the daemon.json file
There is an option

"data-root": ""

Let this point to the desired directory and restart docker service

You can find an example at:

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/virtualization/windowscontainers/manage-docker/configure-docker-daemon

Take care of existing images and data in the current data dir.

I cannot test this because not using docker on windows - hope that's what you are looking for!

Comment: This isnt my issue, this only changes where containers are stored and where it pull things to, it doesnt change Docker' placement.